# Pin addressing (ARM SAM D series) for IO and SERCOM

Tags: arm, atmel

Not sure if I am looking in the wrong place, but I am having hard time to find some step by step code, that show how to manipulate pins IO, and to control I2C, SPI and USART.

Digging the interweb, I did find 2 examples that show IO on a pin, to turn on a LED, using Atmel studio 7

```
#include <asf.h>

#define F_CPU sysclk_get_cpu_hz()
#define __DELAY_CYCLE_INTRINSICS__

int main (void)
{
    board_init();
    PORT ->Group[0].DIRSET.reg = PORT_PA10;
    while (1)
    {
        PORT ->Group[0].OUTSET.reg = PORT_PA10;
    }
}
```

In another example, the same operation of turning on a pin is done in a quite different way, with the extra of the delay to make the LED blink. I recall this being "ASF", the Atmel API used to facilitate things.

```
#include <asf.h>

int main (void)
{
    system_init();
    delay_init();

    while(true)
    {
        delay_ms(250);
        port_pin_set_output_level(LED_PIN, LED_ACTIVE);
        delay_ms(250);
        port_pin_set_output_level(LED_PIN, LED_INACTIVE);

    }
}
```

This is all great; I do get some glimpse of how to do things; but I would like now to use SERCOM to communicate with other devices with USART, I2C and SPI. And I am having hard time to get a clear step by step example, for such usage.

I did try to experiment on my own, but now I am at the point where I need something to follow, either a book, tutorial or video. Maybe I find little documentation because I look for examples for a specific chip? But not all ARM chip work in the same way, with the same code, so I am quite lost...being a beginner in ARM programming is not helping either.

Comment: You could try Atmel Start (http://start.atmel.com/). Create a project with your target device, add the functionality you need (pinmux a little), and export it. That should give you the library code you need, as well as some example functions to show you how to use it. There are also full examples there that you can download and play around with.

Comment: Note that this is is about the microcontroller peripherals, not the CPU core, so it actually has nothing to do with ARM and everything to do with Atmel (e.g. I think some of their peripheral blocks might be common to both ARM-based and AVR32-based parts).

Comment: @IvarBonsaksen: there are examples but they are confusing. Most of the time, an API has great examples, but in the case of Atmel, they did a great job with the docs, but for the examples, they related a lot on the eval board, which is different in some aspects. I would like to see a clear example where you start from scratch, but I found only one that show how to enable a pin for a led.

Comment: @Notlikethat: I partially agree, since from my investigation, there are different ways to run code on the ARM chips: one is via direct manipulation of registers, another is as you mention, via the Atmel API libraries, which should facilitate the job and create a common entry point to drive most of their products. Sadly, the examples are sparse, they do not have a clear way to show how to start with a chip, how to assign pins for various serial connections, and how to communicate with a device. It is all explained somehow, but not clearly :(

Comment: The point is that in that "direct manipulation of registers", the registers in question are part of a peripheral designed by Atmel, available only in Atmel parts (unless possibly it's a licensed 3rd-party IP block from the likes of Synopsys). Either way, since you're writing C code, the architecture of the CPU core making those peripheral accesses doesn't make a blind bit of difference - trying to look for general "ARM" resources will probably end up being more confusing than it is helpful...

Comment: ...whereas a quick search for "Atmel SERCOM" turned up things like [this application note](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42116-SAM-I2C-Bus-Driver-Sercom-I2C_Application%20Note_AT03254.pdf) and [this Adafruit article](https://learn.adafruit.com/using-atsamd21-sercom-to-add-more-spi-i2c-serial-ports/overview), which look fairly informative, and don't even feature the word "ARM" beyond the usual copyright guff.

Comment: @Notlikethat; Indeed the register manipulation is what identify the peripherals of that specific micro-controller; although it seems that ASF is the choice if you want to code for different chips of the same manifacturer.  I am trying to learn both the ASF way and the direct way. I would rather go for the way that is easier to program, and that has more users and support.

Comment: I did check the application notes for both I2C and Serial, and for some reason they assume either that you use their eval board, or you already have the pin configured. Regarding the Adafruit article, it assume that you use one of their board; which has already the pinout set for specific usage; while I start with a blank canvas, so I can't do the same. Plus they use Arduino IDE; I am on Atmel Studio, which mix up even more things. I did search quite a lot about the subject, which is why I started to be frustrated at the lack of progress on my side.

Comment: Ultimately, what you have there is a _complex_ system - in a similar vein, you're unlikely to find a particle physics tutorial which doesn't assume you already know about maths, electromagnetism, etc. Personally, I'd recommend either starting with a standard board for one of the high-level abstractions (like Arduino or mbed) to get comfortable with achieving the thing you want, then start digging down to learn what that abstraction layer does; or start with much a simpler system (e.g. 8-bit AVR or baseline PIC) to get comfortable with hardware basics and reading TRMs, then work up from there.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Atmel is one of my favorite manufacturer because their development tools are free, comprehensive and well documented. I particularly like their API as it is easy and flexible to use.
Most of the time, the API is the best solution (implementing your own USB driver/stack for example is very difficult). However, I understand that in some cases you don't want to use the API, but it still is a very good starting point.

What I advise you is to create an example project in Atmel Studio (File/New/Example project). Then, you can copy and paste the bits that you need (you would not infringe the licence as you are still using Atmel parts). For example, there is a "Quick start for the SAM SERCOM USART driver".

If you want documentation on the API, just click on API documentation in the ASF explorer. For example, the SERCOM USART of the SAMD21 is documented [here](http://asf.atmel.com/docs/3.30.1/samd21/html/group__asfdoc__sam0__sercom__usart__group.html) and [here](http://asf.atmel.com/docs/3.30.1/samd21/html/asfdoc_sam0_sercom_usart_exqsg.html).

Comment: Well, is not like I don't want to use their API, I want to use something that is quick to learn and has plenty of examples. As mentioned before, took me weeks to find a clear example about how to use a pin. Atmel is great because of free tools and tons of API, but if you are new at this, and do not use an eval board, things get complicate fast. I did start with the examples; and they use their eval board. I can hook up my chip as the pin definition headers specify, for the eval board, but first I have to understand what am I doing; and that's the bridging missing in the docs and examples.

Comment: I did check the headers that contain the pin definition, and started from there, but then I got stuck because what is in the application docs on Atmel.com, is different from what I see in the example. Even the serial example is a mess, if you look at the different sources. IT would be so much easier, if there would be on the Atmel site; a "level 0" tutorial that show you how to hook up a bare chip, how to enable pins for Serial, I2C and SPI, and then show example "hello world", all using the same coding methodology, and being consistent. The more time I spend looking, the less I code.

Comment: I edited my post to include the link of the SERCOM USART documentation. In there, they explain step by step how to use the API. The only difficulty I believe it for the pin allocation where you need to dig in the header file to find the macros that look like PINMUX_PA22C_SERCOM3_PAD0.